# Using $.post to authenticate user to return custom error / success message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having this jQuery to authenticate users into site, how can I make two actions for success/error returned by login.php? Is it possible to refresh the page on success (for example) and post error message if the login info was not successful in login.php. I hope my question is clear. Here is the code. Right now it just paste the data output from login.php and I do not know how to seperate success/error returned server side.

```
$("#form-login").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $( this ),
        log = $form.find( 'input[name="log"]' ).val(),
        pwd = $form.find( 'input[name="pwd"]' ).val(),
        rememberme = $form.find( 'input[name="rememberme"]' ).val();
    $.post( '/ajax/login.php', { log: log, pwd: pwd, rememberme: rememberme },
        function(data) {
            $(".form-login-status").html(data);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your server side script, return the status as well as the message, like this:

```
$result = array();

if (login_is_successful()) {
    $result['status'] = true;
    $result['message'] = "Logged in";
} else {
    $result['status'] = false;
    $result['message'] = 'Incorrect password';
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

This gives you the flexibility to send any response message from the server side without needing to handle it specially in your client side code. Tomorrow, if you want to send messages 'Incorrect Username' and 'Incorrect Password' separately, you can do so without any change to your JS as long as `$result['status']` remains `false`.

Then in the success handler of your `$.post`, do this:

```
success : function(resp) {
    if (resp.status) {
        //user logged in
        //refresh page
        window.location.reload();
    } else {
        //failed authentication
        alert(resp.message);
    }
}
```

Make sure you set `dataType: 'json'`

**Important Note:**

If authentication fails, the erorr handler in your `$.post` WILL NOT be called, therefore you have to check for failed authentication in your success handler.

The error handler is only called when there is an error in making the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jqxhr-object):

```
$.post("example.php", {},  function() {
      alert("success");
    })
    .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your 'success' handler, you'll need to process a flag returned by the requested URI that states whether or not the credentials authenticated the user or not. You'll want to branch your logic based on that logic.